# R Geom Jitter Labeling Dots

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, jitter

I'm making a Jitter figure related to real estate. The variables plotted are the building and the delinquency status ( for ex. too small, small, medium, high, too high), which is a factor. In the data set, I also have the name of the resident and the balance he owes.

This is the chart:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yQXv.png]

I want to add the name of the resident that is included on this chart.

I tried to use:

```
geom_text(aes(label=resident))
```

I have used this before, but it seems is not working, it is showing me this warning.

```
In argument: balance = as.integer(gsub("\\$", "", balance))
```

Name of the respective should be aside the dot. This is the code:

```
eigpm %>% clean_names() %>%
  mutate(d_status = str_sub(eigpm$Delinquency.Status,1,2)) %>%
  mutate(balance = as.integer(gsub("\\$", "", balance)),
         d_status = as.integer(d_status)
         ) %>%
  mutate(property_name = as.factor(property_name)) %>%
  mutate(delinquency_status = as.factor(delinquency_status)) %>%
  arrange(desc(balance)) %>%
  filter(! is.na(delinquency_status)) %>%
  filter(delinquency_status!="") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=property_name, y=d_status, color=property_name, size=balance)) +
  geom_jitter(alpha=0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1:11)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90),
        legend.position = "bottom") +
  labs(x= "Properties", y="Delinquency Status") +
  guides(color=F) +
  geom_text(aes(label=resident))
```

Comment: Is this a real dataset, or a 'pretend' example dataset?

Comment: Hello @LeroyTyrone, it is the real dataset.

Comment: In that case,it is highly likely that you have breached privacy laws by posting identifiable information about those people on a public forum. To avoid this, create anonymised data when posting. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?